# How to access property of suggestions coming from my AutoSuggest ( custom made using .filter() )

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, javascript-objects

I am displaying suggestions from the suggestions variable in my `this.state` using

```
suggestions = this.state.products
            .map((item) => item.name)
            .sort()
            .filter((v) => regex.test(v));
```

my `this.state.products` look like this:

```
products = [
  {
    name: "Item1",
    category: "stock",
    id: 123
  },
  {
    name: "Item1",
    category: "product",
    id: 456
  },
  {
    name: "Item2",
    category" "item"
  }
]
```

But `this.state.suggestions` only looks like this (assuming the user input is Item1 or close to that):

```
suggestions = ["Item1", "Item1"]
```

How can I make it look like:

```
suggestions = [
  {
    name: "Item1",
    category: "stock"
  },
  {
    name: "Item1",
    category: "product"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure the object while `mapping` it and pass only the name property to `filter`.
Something like this:

```
suggestions = this.state.products
            .map(({name, category}) => ({name, category}))
            .sort()
            .filter(({name}) => regex.test(name));
```

Comment: You my sir, are a hero!

Comment: One more thing, can you help me finding the index of object containing given `id`? I have `array = [ { ... id: 489 }, { ... id: 978 } ]` and want to return the index of object containing `id` that is equal to my variable `currentId`. Any idea how to do that?